# What is the correct syntax to write a Filter query in Realm .NET using the "IN" keyword

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm building an App with Xamarin using [MongoDB Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/) for my Database.
Realm allows you to use string based query language with a Filter function they expose. They link [this](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) NSPredicate cheat sheet to help guide you in how to write your queries. I am however unable to get an "IN" query working.

In my code I currently have this class which I'm trying to query on:

```
public class Person : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my query looks like this:

```
var foundPersons = realm.All<Person>().Filter("Id IN { 1,2 }");
```

When running this will give an exception: Realms.Exceptions.RealmException: 'Invalid predicate: 'Id IN { 1,2 }': syntax error, unexpected '{''

I have also tried the query without curly braces:

```
var foundPersons = realm.All<Person>().Filter("Id IN 1,2");
```

Which will give me the following error: Realms.Exceptions.RealmException: 'Invalid predicate: 'Id IN 1,2': syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end of file'

Other ways I've tried are using [] brackets and using quotation marks but they all give Errors.

How do I write this query in the correct way so it will return all Persons that have either 1 or 2 as their ID?

Comment: Why don't you do: `var foundPersons = realm.All<Person>().Where(p => new int[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(p.Id));`? See the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/examples/read-and-write-data/#filter-queries-based-on-object-properties

Comment: Tried this it gives a System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'Contains' is not supported'

Comment: That link is for Swift/ObjC NSPredicates which you don't appear to be using? Also - it maybe a good idea to stick with standard practice of naming your primary key as `_id`

Comment: They actually link to these NSPredicates themself saying they support them in the release notes for .Net Realm 3.0.0 here: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/releases?page=5

Comment: I think the answer is in the docs - *The Realm JavaScript SDK supports querying based on a language inspired by* - with "inspired by" being the key. Looking though the official documentation there is no mention of using IN so it doesn't appear to be supported. And now there's an answer providing a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported - see [this discussion](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/discussions/2741) on Github. The only workaround is to generate the string predicate as multiple equality statements combined with `OR`:

```
var values = new[] { 1, 2 }; // Or however you get them
var filter = string.Join(" OR ", values.Select(v => $"(Id == {v})"));
var results = Realm.All<Person>().Filter(filter);
```

Comment: Alright guess I will be using this option for now then. I got confused because on the NSPredicate Cheatsheet it actually has the "supported by Realm" dot next to it. https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yeah, it's a little confusing because the Realm Query Language is heavily influenced by NSPredicate but it's not 1:1. The NSPredicate cheatsheet is accurate for the Swift/Obj C SDK, but not for the other SDKs. Here's the docs page that should be authoritative about the supported operations: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/reference/realm-query-language/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make filter into `list` field in latest `Realm.Net`

```
<PackageReference Include="Realm">
      <Version>11.6.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

```
QueryArgument[] arguments = new QueryArgument[] {"volvo","audi","honda"};
var result = realm.All<Item>().Filter("ANY car == {$0, $1, $2}", arguments);
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#query-formats